# Prompt for customized message in mass-emails with Access VBA

Tags: email, ms-access, outlook, vba

I'm trying to put together a tool to send mass emails to a query of users from a database table. I'm using the SendObject method and it works well enough.

```
SendObject(ObjectType, ObjectName, OutputFormat, To, Cc, Bcc, Subject, MessageText, EditMessage, TemplateFile)
```

I manually modify the VBA code when I need a new message; using vbNewLine to denote line breaks in the MessageText string field.

I want to create a prompt to ask the user to type in the message, and automatically format it with line breaks when the macro runs.

The emails are newsletters several paragraphs long tailored to each recipient (e.g. John Doe = Dear John Doe, Gary Stu = Dear Gary Stu).

`SendObject` can be set to prompt the user with an option to edit the email before sending it but each of the modifications is unique to each individual email.

Comment: What exactly are you editing manually in VBA? Are you copy pasting the names directly into the code? It seems to me that what you need is an elaborate String manipulation function that puts the message string together as needed. That would be indeed possible. Give us an example what you have and what you want it to be if you need more help.

Comment: What I have looks something like

`DoCmd.SendObject , "", "", rs![Email], "", "", "Congratulations on your hire!", "Dear [first name] [last name] & vbNewLine &  Let me be the first to congratulate you on your offer!", False, ""`

I would modify the [first name] and [last name] to match each recipient's while the rest of the MessageText field would stay the same. My goal is to have some kind of form where I could type the universal message contents in and have it automatically line break & have the unique fields filled in automatically based on the recipient's information in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make variables to generate body of email or subject or both.

For picking up data from recordset, assuming `tblContactData` table with first name, last name, emailID etc.

```
    Dim strSubject as string, strSubjectLine as string
    Dim strMessageBody as string, strFirstName as string, strLastName as string, recContactData as DAO.recordset
    
set recContactData = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("Select  * from tblContactData")

'Loop all the contacts for email
Do Until recContactData.EOF  = True
'    strSubjectLine = InputBox("Enter Subject Line", "Input")
    strSubjectLine = "Ref No" & recContactData.Fields("ContactID")
    strSubject = "Your email , " & strSubjectLine
    
    'strFirstName = InputBox("Enter First Name", "Input")
    strFirstName = recContactData.Fields("FirstName")
    'strLastName = InputBox("Enter Last Name", "Input")
    strLastName = recContactData.Fields("LastName")

    strMessageBody = "Hello " & strFirstName & strLastName &  vbNewLine & vbCrLf & " Let me first congratulate you for registering this program"
    
    SendObject(, "", "", recContactData.Fields("EmailID"), "", "", strSubject, strMessageBody,false, "")

  recContactData.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I properly explained my intentions. The idea is to have the dynamic fields such as FirstName and LastName dynamically pulled from the table entry while the message itself have an input box that automatically recognizes paragraph breaks as vbNewLine and inputs all of that into the MessageText field.

Comment: why do you need input box then ? we can loop recordset, in my above code replace inputbox with the appropriate field of recordset. For new line and carriage feed you don't need input box. but if you want to have that decided on the inputbox, we can write logic, but I don't see any such intention.

Comment: The idea behind the input box is to lower the hurdle of editing VBA code for my coworkers. They're not very technical people and I'm afraid they would be too put off by having to wrap vbNewLine around their paragraph breaks. If there were an input field where they could type their standard message and have it automatically parse the input with vbNewLines, they would be more likely to accept an automated email solution. 

This recordset loop was what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You create a form that has two textboxes, txtFirstName, txtLastName. Then create a button and put this code in the button click event:

Try this VBA code:

```
Sub btnSend_Click()
  Dim message as String    
  'Make sure to handle the case if textboxes are empty

  message = "Dear " & txtFirstName.value & " " & txtLastName.value & ", " & _
            vbNewLine & "Let me be the first to congratulate you on your offer!"

  DoCmd.SendObject , "", "", rs![Email], "", "", "Congratulations on your hire!",  message , False, ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I properly explained my intentions. The idea is to have the dynamic fields such as FirstName and LastName dynamically pulled from the table entry while the message itself have an input box that automatically recognizes paragraph breaks as vbNewLine and inputs all of that into the MessageText field.